# .htaccess url routing weird behaviour

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

I have this in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^en/?(.*)$ $1?lang=en [QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page.php?route=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

The task would be to get the language paramater. If it's https://example.com/, then language will be the default (hu), but if it's https://example.com/en/, then it's obviously en. This part works fine.
However, on page.php, the route variable gets duplicated if url has the en/ (or de/, fr/, etc..) prefix, for example:

```
//https://example.com/en/air-conditioners
$_GET['route'] = 'air-conditioners/air-conditioners'; //❌
$_GET['lang'] = 'en'; //✔

//https://example.com/en/air-conditioners/
$_GET['route'] = 'air-conditioners//air-conditioners/'; //❌
$_GET['lang'] = 'en'; //✔
```

I'm not the greatest regexologyst, so help would be really appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, after too many hours of research, basically i had to give a DPI flag to the first rule. (Also QSA was unnecessary in my case)
Like this:

```
RewriteRule ^en/?(.*)$ $1?lang=en [NC,DPI]
```